# Programmatically access external list associated column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, bcs

Hi I have 2 external lists 'A' and 'B'. with an associated column in A, that looks up for B.
When i view/edit item  in browser, it shows correct values as shown in picture below.

[image]

But when i try to access the list in code, i can access all column values, but associated  column value comes null.
The code look something like this :

```
                            items = listReports.GetItems();

                            System.Collections.Generic.List<ReportItem> reportItems = new List<ReportItem>();
                            foreach (SPListItem it in items)
                            {
                                if (it != null)
                                {

                                    ReportItem item = new ReportItem();
                // extItem comes null
                var extItem = it["ExtCol"];
                // extItem comes null

                  DateTime date;
                                    if (DateTime.TryParse(it["GeneratedOn"].ToString(), out date))
                                    {
                                        item.dateGenerated = date.Date;
                                    }

                                    DateTime time;
                                    if (DateTime.TryParse(it["GeneratedOn"].ToString(), out time))
                                    {
                                        item.timeGenerated = time.Date;
                                    }

                                    reportItems.Add(item);

                                }


                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but, "ExtCol" - is that rigth name for field in your external type? For external items sharepoint may substitute a name of external item/column in the source field name.